# Hyperledger Fabric and Ethereum Blockchain Integration

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

How can I connect Hyperledger Fabric to the ethereum blockchain so as to make payments. I am recording the number of tokens to be alloted in the hyperledger system I want to access the data and then make payment through Ethereum ERC20 tokens. However I tried using REST API, but they are not providing much of the security. How can I do it the right secure way ?